# How to make a Jumbotron w/ background image responsive? (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out how to make the jumbotron with a bg image responsive. I try to resize the tab but the image does not move with it. Not sure if that makes sense. I want the full image to display and when I resize it, I do not want it to distort (which it doesn't).

HTML CODE:

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
```

---

CSS CODE:

```
    body {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 396px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

I also have a navbar underneath the jumbotron.

HTML CODE (navbar):

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class = "collpase navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class = "nav-item"><a href = "#">home</a></li>
                <li class = "nav-item"><a href = "#">learn</a></li>
                <li class = "nav-item"><a href = "#">about</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

CSS CODE (navbar):

```
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 75px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    width: 1170px;
}
.nav-item {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: black;
}
li:first-child {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}
li:last-child {
    padding-right: 3.7em;
}
```

[The webpage on desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQfPj.png)

[This is the jumbotron on a mobile website. I want the full image to display, not just the left half.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpoxl.png)

Comment: use  `background-size: contain;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `50% 50%` to the end of the `background-image`.

As long as you keep `background-size:cover` this should look better.

```
 background-image: url(images/header.png) 50% 50%;
```

^ is just going to keep the image centered whilst `backgbround-size:cover` keeps the image at the same height as your jumbotron.